# How to set default value in React select dropdown and append remaining values dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm working on a React application where I have a form with a select dropdown. When the user clicks on the 'Edit' button, I want the value of the 'uom' field of the selected product record to be set as the default value in the select dropdown. Additionally, I want to dynamically append the remaining values from the 'UnitMasterData' array after the default value. Currently, my code populates the select dropdown with all values from 'UnitMasterData' without setting a default value. How can I achieve this functionality?

I am attaching my code below -

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, generatePath, Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import FormRange from 'react-bootstrap/esm/FormRange';

function App() {

  const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal)

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    productid1: '',
    product_name1: '',
    product_category1: '',
    uom1: '',
    purchase_rate1: '',
    sales_rate1: '',
    mrp1: '',
    opqty1: '',
    clqty1: '',
    status1: '',
    product_id_hidden1: '',
    operationtype1: 'Add Product'
  });
  
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const [UnitMasterData, setUnitMasterData] = useState([]);
  //2) using axios
  useEffect(() => {
  // Fetch data from the specified URL
  axios.get('http://localhost/api_link/codeigniter_part/public/UnitMaster')

    .then((response) => {
        // Access the response data directly using response.data
        setUnitMasterData(response.data.UnitMasterData);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
  }, []);


  function getdatabyrecordarray(record) {
    // console.log(record.customer_mp_id);
    setFormData({
      productid1: record.productid,
      product_name1: record.product_name,
      product_category1: record.product_category,
      uom1: record.uom,
      purchase_rate1: record.purchase_rate,
      sales_rate1: record.sales_rate,
      mrp1: record.mrp,
      opqty1: record.opqty,
      clqty1: record.clqty,
      status1: record.status,
      operationtype1: 'Edit Customer'
    });
  }

  return (

  <div className="container" style={{color: '#4229cb', fontWeight: '500' ,backgroundColor: 'rgb(255 255 255)'}} >
    <h1 style={{ color: 'white', backgroundColor: '#4229cb', padding: '5px' }} className="text-center"> Product Master</h1>
      <nav style={{ marginTop: -8 }} className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>  
        </div>  
      </nav>

 <div className="col-md-4">
              <label htmlFor="id-uom" className="form-label">UOM</label>
              <select className="form-select" id="id-uom" name="uom" value = {formData.uom1} onChange = {handleInputChange} >
              {UnitMasterData.map((umd) => (
                <option
                  value={umd.unitname}
                >
                  {umd.unitname}
                </option>
              ))}
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

    <div className="row mt-4">
      <div className="col-md-12 table-responsive-xl">
        <table className="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Prod. Code</th>
              <th>Production Name</th>
              <th>Category</th>
              <th>UOM</th>
              <th>Op Qty</th>
              <th>Cl Qty</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {ProductMasterData.map((p) => (

          <tr>
            <td>{p.productid}</td>
            <td>{p.product_name}</td>
            <td>{p.product_category}</td>
            <td>{p.uom}</td>
            <td>{p.opqty}</td>
            <td>{p.clqty}</td>
            <td>
              <button onClick={() => getdatabyrecordarray(p)} className="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</button>
              {/* <Link to={generatePath(routes.customerDetails, { customerid1: c.customer_mp_id })}  className="btn btn-success btn-sm">edit</Link> */}

              &nbsp;<button onClick={(event) => confirmDelete(event, p.productid)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm ml-1">
              Delete
              </button>

            </td>
          </tr>
          ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  
  );
}

export default App;
```

While addressing this concern and considering my limited experience with React, I have tried mapping through the 'UnitMasterData' array and populating the select dropdown using the map function. However, I'm unable to set the default value for the 'uom' field of the selected product record. I expected the select dropdown to display the 'uom' value of the selected product record at the top and the remaining values from 'UnitMasterData' below it.
I also attempted to resolve the issue by adding a value attribute to the select box. While this successfully displays the uom value of the selected record at the top, it prevents the selection of any other option from the dropdown.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to be a default value in the `select` element? There is no data available to be a default value when the component mounts.

Comment: I appreciate your question. In the context of my React component, I'm aiming to set the default value of the select element to be the 'uom' (unit of measure) value of the selected record when the 'Edit' button is clicked. The data for this default value is already present in the 'formData' state when the component mounts. The challenge lies in dynamically appending the remaining 'UnitMasterData' values to the select dropdown after setting this default value. I hope this provides more clarity on my objective. Please let me know if further details are needed.

Comment: It seems to me that the form data isn't fetched/set until the edit button is clicked and `getdatabyrecordarray` is called, whereas the `useEffect` hook runs when the component mounts and will set the `UnitMasterData` state. Are you ok with these events happening in this order, and the end result is for the records `uom` value to be in the list of options?

Comment: The 'uom' values are already present in the unitmasterdata array. I want that, after clicking on the 'Edit' button, which is present in each row of the table, the 'uom' value from that particular record should be set as the initial value in the 'uom' select box. This means that after clicking the 'Edit' button, the value present in formdata.uom1 should be placed at the beginning of the select box, and the remaining values from the unitmasterdata array should come after it in the select box.

Comment: I think I understand your UX now, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are just missing providing the `uom` value of the currently selected record as a selectable option.

You can't just use the `formData.uom1` value because you are selecting new values and updating the form data, which would constantly change the first option to whatever else is being selected from the list (*when a new record isn't being selected*).

- Add a new state to hold the initial `uom` value
- Update the uom default value when a record is selected
- Conditionally render this default uom as the first option

Example:

```
const [defaultUom, setDefaultUom] = useState();

...

function getdatabyrecordarray(record) {
  setDefaultUom(record.uom);

  setFormData({
    productid1: record.productid,
    product_name1: record.product_name,
    product_category1: record.product_category,
    uom1: record.uom,
    purchase_rate1: record.purchase_rate,
    sales_rate1: record.sales_rate,
    mrp1: record.mrp,
    opqty1: record.opqty,
    clqty1: record.clqty,
    status1: record.status,
    operationtype1: 'Edit Customer'
  });
}

...

<select
  className="form-select"
  id="id-uom"
  name="uom1" // <-- should match `formData.uom1` property
  value={formData.uom1}
  onChange={handleInputChange}
>
  {/* uom option from selected record when available */}
  {defaultUom && (
    <option value={defaultUom}>
      {defaultUom}
    </option>
  )}

  {/* dynamically fetched options */}
  {UnitMasterData.map((umd) => (
    <option key={umd.unitname} value={umd.unitname}>
      {umd.unitname}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, Drew! It's working exactly as I wanted. I also added some code to ensure that the value in defaultUom doesn't repeat in the subsequent 'uom' options:


{UnitMasterData.map((umd) => (
  umd.unitname !== defaultUom ? (
    <option key={umd.unitname} value={umd.unitname}>
      {umd.unitname}
    </option>
  ) : null
))}


This prevents the default 'uom' value from being duplicated in the following options. Appreciate your help!"